# What will be the product of Wolff–Kishner reduction in presence of hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

[image: my textbook exercise gives this reaction]
My textbook exercise gives this reaction.
What I observe is only the alkene part at the bottom changes to alkane.

I know the procedure of ordinary Wolff–Kishner reaction (shown in img given below), but peroxide makes it difficult.[image: Wolff–Kishner Reaction]

1 and 2 represents the catalyst addition order.

Please explain why this happens?
Does this reaction remove double bonds?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! I suggest you explore "diimide". Wolff-Kishner is not involved. Note that the carbonyl is intact.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I think you are right. This Wikipedia page helps: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductions_with_diimide . I had no idea of it.

Comment: FYI: The chemistry was well-known prior to the advent of Wikipedia. Yes, it is right.

Comment: Ofc, it was. I used Wikipedia to understand. Your comment was helpful.

Comment: @user391330 if you got your answer, feel free to self-answer your question. Self-answering is encouraged here. It will help future readers and also helps you in earning some reps.

Comment: I understand the mechanism (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/DiimideMech1.png) now . But, the H2O2 part still worries me.